# Solve: $\sqrt{x + 3 + \sqrt{x + 14}} + \sqrt{x+3 - \sqrt{x + 14}} =4 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

I tried:
$\sqrt{x +14} = t$

$\implies \sqrt{x+3 + t} + \sqrt{x+3 - t} = 4$

But I think it is the hard way. Any ideas?

Comment: Try some numbers for which x+14 is a square.

Comment: If you set $t$ as you did, then $x - 3 = t^2 - 11$. This gives a nicer expression, depending only on $t$. Don't know if this helps but it is definitely easier to work with that what you have at this stage.

Comment: Let $x + 14 = t^2$. Since $4$ is a rational number $(4 = \frac 82)$ then none of the radicals on the $LHS$ (*Left Hand Side* of the equation) must be irrational, so $x + 3 + \sqrt {x + 14} = u^2$ and $x + 3 - \sqrt {x + 14} = v^2$. Now you have $u + v = 4$, and now you can square both sides, $FOIL$ (in simpler terms, *factor*) the $LHS$ and subtract both sides by like terms. Reply if you want a full answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The domain gives $x\geq-3$ and $(x+3)^2\geq x+14$.

Now, our equation it's
$$\left(\sqrt{x + 3 + \sqrt{x + 14}} + \sqrt{x+3 - \sqrt{x + 14}}\right)^2 =16 $$ or
$$2x+6+2\sqrt{(x+3)^2-x-14}=16$$ or
$$\sqrt{x^2+5x-5}=5-x.$$
Now, we get also $5-x\geq0$, for which we obtain
$$x^2+5x-5=x^2-10x+25$$ or
$$x=2,$$ which is valid.

Answer (score 2):

after squaring we get
$$x+3+\sqrt{x+14}+x+3-\sqrt{x+14}+2\sqrt{(x+3)^2-(x+4)}=16$$
simplifying we obtain
$$\sqrt{(x+3)^2-(x+14)}=5-x$$
squaring again
$$(x+3)^2-(x+14)=25+x^2-10x$$
Can you finish?

Comment: yes thank you for your another useful answer Mr. Sonnhard Graubner

Comment: I think the first line should have $16$ instead of $10$, and the second line should be $5-x$

Comment: yes it is just corrected